# Is there a Laravel route link Angularjs/otherwise?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. As I asked in title, is there any route declaration in Laravel like AngularJS(otherwise) ? For example, I'll define some routes and all other URI requests will redirect to a certain page/index page/ error page ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you're looking for a catch all route.

According to the [Laravel Snippets sites](http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/catch-all-route), if you add the following to the end of your `app/routes.php`, this should give you what you want.

```
Route::get('{slug?}', function(){
    return 'Catch All';
})->where('slug', '.+');
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly didn't even try to Google this: `laravel routes`.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing

Comment: Sorry, still couldn't find anyone like that. Can you please mention?

Comment: I don't really understand...are you looking for a catch-all?

Answer (score 0):

In your Laravel application, locate to app/routes.php

That's where your routes are kept. You can define them like so:

```
Route::get('/home', function() {
    return View::make('pages.home');
});
```

Or to call a controller:

```
Route::get('/home', ['uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

You can call HTTP verbs as well, like so:

```
Route::post('/some/form', ['uses' => 'YourController@process']);
```

Please see here for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing